# Possible to zip list of file streams asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, zip

I'm writing a webservice that needs to get a list of file streams and zip them all up. I've written some code to do that, but the problem is that it's sequential, so when trying to zip a lot of files, it takes too long. ~10 files is taking almost 2 seconds, even though the files are only 20kb. Is there some way zip all the files at the same time? This is what I have now:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(some_stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var file in list_of_files)
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = archive.CreateEntry(file.name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        using (Stream zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
        {
            await file.stream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to create a list of tasks instead of awaiting, the ZipArchive will throw an error that entries cannot be created while the previous entry is still open.

Comment: So what's the long running synchronous work?  The only long running work you've showed is asynchronous.

Comment: Unless i'm misunderstanding, even though it's async, i'm forced to `await` it, so it ends up only zipping one file at at time.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make it synchronous.  That makes it sequential.  **Big** difference.

Comment: Gotcha. Question, albeit a bit reworded still stands if you have any ideas.

Comment: The error message sounds pretty self explanatory.  What about it don't you understand?

Comment: I understand the error. I'm trying to figure out the correct/different way to achieve what I want. I'm assuming there's some way to zip 10 20kb files in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: if im understanding correctly zipping one file at a time taking so long seems to be the problem. YYou might want to have a look at Parallel.Foreach (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) to start zipping multiply files at the same time.

Comment: @R.Bechtel They *did* copy the files in parallel (although `Parallel.ForEach` isn't an appropriate way of doing that as the work is asynchronous, not synchronous), and that resulted in the error described in the question.

Comment: I'm surprised it takes so long. Are those files on network share or something? Anyway, as error message says, ZipArchive class does not support writing multiple entries in parallel.

Comment: Are you aware of an alternative to ZipArchive that does?